# How to replace a multi-character character constant with one character

Tags: c, string

I'm attempting to replace `'%7C'` with a `'|'` in C but i'm getting a multi-character character constant warning. I was wondering if it was possible to do this and if so how? I was attempting using the code below but it gave this warning.

**Parse.c**

```
char *parse(char *command){
 char * newCommand = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*35);
     newCommand = strtok(command, " ");
     newCommand = strtok(NULL, "/run?command= ");
     for(int i = 0; i<strlen(newCommand); i++){
          if(newCommand[i] == '+')
          {
              newCommand[i] = ' ';
          }
          if(newCommand[i] == '%7C')
          {
               newCommand[i] = '|';
          }
     }
    return newCommand;
  }
```

Comment: `'%7C'` isn't a valid character as far as I know. It is a string of three characters.

Comment: The reasoning for it is i'm implementing an HTTP server and when the user types in `|` it goes back to the `%7C`

Comment: That is completely understandable. The `"%7C"` is the URL encoded version of the `'|'` character. However, you need to realize that you are replacing a **substring** with a **single character**. The logic to do this will be more complicated than a simple assignment.

Comment: Aside::You are unnecessarily allocating memory and overwriting it next line causing memory leaks..

Comment: the memory isnt the issue here and this code is a piece of something larger so the memory allocation is needed i thought. Regardless, @Code-Apprentice is there a way to do this then that will work to maintain the string? such as `ls+-l+%7C+wc+-l` becoming `ls -l | wc -l` atm it become `ls -l %7C wc -l`

Comment: @BretHasel Yes, there is a way to do this. It is called unencoding. If you are implementing this yourself, you need to write an algorithm that replaces a substring of your input with a character. Are you only concerned about the | character or do you need general unencoding for all possible characters?

Comment: only the | character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-character constants are not portable and should generally be avoided.  Your code comes under the 'general' category.

Part of the solution to your problem is to do a string comparison (with `strncmp`):

```
if (strncmp(&newCommand[i], "%7C", 3) == 0)
{
    newCommand[i] = '|';
}
```

However, you also need to remove the `7C`.  That requires more surgery on the loop:

```
int tgt = 0;
int len = strlen(newCommand);
for (int src = 0; src < len; src++)
{
    if (newCommand[src] == '+')
    {
        newCommand[tgt++] = ' ';
    }
    else if (strncmp(newCommand[i], "%7C", 3) == 0)
    {
        newCommand[tgt++] = '|';
        src += 2;
    }
    else
        newCommand[tgt++] = newCommand[src];
 }
 newCommand[tgt] = '\0';
```

This maintains two indexes into the `newCommand` array, one from which you're reading (`src`) and one to which you're writing (`tgt` — `dst` would be an alternative name).  The `src += 2;` skips over the `7C` after replacing `%` with `|`.

<sup>*Uncompiled code!*</sup>

Also, in your function you have:

```
char *newCommand = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*35);
newCommand = strtok(command, " ");
```

This immediately leaks the allocated memory.  Maybe you need to use `strdup()` or:

```
char *newCommand = malloc(strlen(command) + 1);
if (newCommand == NULL) …report error and bail out…
strcpy(newCommand, command);
```

And the next line:

```
newCommand = strtok(NULL, "/run?command= ");
```

splits on any sequence of any of the characters in the constant string; it does not look for that string.  If you want to look for the string, then you need `strstr()` instead, and you need to run `strtok()` first, perhaps, to get the right starting point (maybe `newCommand = strtok(NULL, "")`, then `char *end = strstr(newCommand, "/run?command= ");` — and check for null pointers returned.

With the revised allocation, you need a new symbol to record the pointers returned by `strtok()` — such as `char *token;`.

All in all, there's a lot of work needed on your code.